# Can I "override" the width of an HTML element with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm doing some work with CSS, and I have an `<li>` element with a `<div>` element inside of it. The `<div>` element assumes the width of the enclosing `<li>` element, but the text content inside the `<div>` is wider than the `<li>` (and therefore goes onto two lines). What I want to do is make the `<div>` the same width as its longest text element, does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks.

```
<ul style="display: inline-block; list-item-style: none">
  <li id="foo" style="float: left; list-style-type: none; position: relative;">
    <a href="...">brief text</a>
    <div id="bar" style="position: absolute; width=???">
      <ul>
        <li>a long chunk of text</li>
        <li>an even longer piece of text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Right now, the width of `div#bar` is equal to 100% of the width of its enclosing element, `li#foo`, and the width of `li#foo` is equal to the width of the text in its `<a>` tag (plus padding and borders). What I want to do is make `div#bar` be the width of `<li>an even longer piece of text</li>`, but I can't figure out how to accomplish that, even with Javascript.... or am I going to be forced to use an absolute measurement for the width? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why div#bar has absolute positioning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strip out the position attributes from #foo and #bar.

Then add:

```
<style type="text/css">
#bar li { white-space:nowrap !important; }
</style>
```

Comment: +1 for clean solution, and paying attention to the OP wanting it to grow with content.

Comment: Thank you. Not quite sure what those position attributes were doing there in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

put `!important` after the style value before `;`

### Sample:

```
#element{ width:500px!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

`width:500px` instead of `width=500px` (replace 500 with desired width)

http://jsfiddle.net/p4YNA/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul style="display: inline-block; list-item-style: none">
  <li id="foo" style="float: left; list-style-type: none; position: relative;">
 <a href="...">brief text</a>
 <div id="bar" style="float:left;">
   <ul>
  <li>a long chunk of text</li>
  <li>an even longer piece of text</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can remove the display: inline-block from the outer `<ul/>` and remove float: left from the foo `<li/>` then the list will expand to the longest element.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity), you <del>can</del> can't (see edit) overide it by using a combination of rules that is stronger than the element style.

```
Element style (style="XXX") = 1000
Id (#id)                    = 100
Class (.class)              = 10
element (ie: p)             = 1
```

So if you are able to specify a css rule with more than 1000, I think you could do it.

**EDIT**:
After some test, if found that a style defined directly in an element can't be overiden by css with this method. Sorry.

Comment: You can also use `!important` to override which basically resets the weight attribute and is now only competing against other "!important" styles.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use a fixed width for the `#bar`. A second solution is to remove `position:absolute;` from `#bar`.